# Displaying SQL rows to columns where the row count may vary

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a **main** table as below

```
ID    Latest_rating
---  --------------
1      3
2      5
```

then I have a **main_audit** table which shows the rating change history as below

```
ID   rating  rating_change_date
--   ------  ------------------
1      2     26-Sep-15
1      4     16-Apr-14
1      3     10-Mar-13
2      3     04-Apr-15
2      2     01-Oct-13
```

So I have to join both the tables and should display as following

```
ID  Latest_Rating  1st_Rating rating_change_date 2nd_rating rating_change_date
--  -------------  ---------- ------------------ ---------- ------------------
1         3            3          10-Mar-13          4          16-Apr-14
2         5            2          01-Oct-13          3          04-Apr-15
```

I should display as 1st rating, 2nd rating, 3rd rating, 4 rating in columns as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per your comment you can either combine if the rating is the same and take the minimum date that way if there are 3 changes 1 & 2 are the same 1 & 2 become combined and the 3rd change moves up to number 2.  Also there is no need for the 3 queries you can just do it in 1 nested select with a join and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    m.Id
    ,m.Latest_rating
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN t.RateChangeNum = 1 THEN t.rating END) as first_rating
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN t.RateChangeNum = 1 THEN t.MinRatingChangeDate END) as first_rating_change_date
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN t.RateChangeNum = 2 THEN t.rating END) as first_rating
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN t.RateChangeNum = 2 THEN t.MinRatingChangeDate END) as first_rating_change_date
FROM
    main m
    INNER JOIN
    (
       SELECT
          ID
          ,rating
          ,MIN(rating_change_date) as MinRatingChangeDate
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY MIN(rating_change_date)) as RateChangeNum
       FROM
          main_audit a
       GROUP BY
          ID
          ,rating
    ) t
    ON m.Id = t.ID
GROUP BY
    m.Id
    ,m.Latest_rating
```

As far as your comment concerning the number of changes varying.  You can either hard code to the full number you think may or may not be there and the fields will just be null if there are not that many changes or you need to turn to dynamic sql.

The reason for conditional aggregation instead of PIVOT is because you need to aggregate multiple columns, if you only wanted the rating or the date then you could use PIVOT and it would be a bit less code writing (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `row_number()` and aggregation.  The tricky part is:

```
select ma.id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then rating end) as first_rating,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then rating_change_date end) as first_rating_change_date,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then ma.rating end) as second_rating,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then ma.rating_change_date end) as second_rating_change_date
from (select ma.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by rating_change_date desc) as seqnum
      from main_audit ma
     ) ma
group by id;
```

You can then combine them:

```
with ma as (
      select ma.id,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then rating end) as first_rating,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then rating_change_date end) as first_rating_change_date,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then ma.rating end) as second_rating,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then ma.rating_change_date end) as second_rating_change_date
      from (select ma.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by id order by rating_change_date desc) as seqnum
            from main_audit ma
           ) ma
      group by id
     )
select m.id, m.latest_rating,
       ma.first_rating, ma.first_rating_change_date,
       ma.second_rating, ma.second_rating_change_date
from main m join
     ma
     on m.id = ma.id;
```

Comment: thank you for your help, also if I have to compare the ratings and if 1st and 2nd ratings are same shouldn't display the 2nd rating only 1st should remain. How do I do it? Also my number of previous ratings vary so I might have to display 1st,2nd,3rd,4th or 1st,2nd or 1st,2nd,3rd this way. number of previous rating records might vary. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: @MitraVinda You should probaby put that information in the question. But it sounds like you could use `lag()` to eliminate the consecutive identical ratings: `(select * from
    (select ma.*,
      row_number() over (partition by id order by rating_change_date desc,
    lag(rating) over (partition by id order by rating_change_date) as last_rating) ma0
where rating <> last_rating or last_rating is null) ma`